# How can I handle when a UdpClient is listening on an address which is no longer available?

Tags: c#, udpclient

I'm using a UdpClient, bound to a provided end point, to listen for incoming packets. My code is as follows:

```
        ... 
        string myIpAddress = "192.168.1.100";
        int myPort = 50000;

        IPEndPoint selfEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(myIpAddress), myPort);
        IPEndPoint anySourceEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

        UdpClient receivingClient = new UdpClient();
        receivingClient.Client.Bind(selfEndPoint); // Can throw.

        receivingClient.Receive(ref anySourceEndPoint);
        ...
```

If an interface with the IP address '192.168.1.100' does not exist, it throws a SocketException` (as expected). In the case were such an interface exists, the UdpClient binds successfully and waits for an incoming packet. My problem is as follows.

How can detect the case where I am blocking on the `Receive` and the interface's address is no longer available?

For example, the application is running and is waiting for incoming packets. The user then disables the network interface on the system. The application still assumes it can receive packets, even though it cannot.

The closes I've come is setting a `ReceiveTimeout` on the client and re-creating/binding a UdpClient when this timeout occurs; I'm hoping for an alternative or any other suggestions.

Comment: Do I understand correctly? You want to be able to handle the user disabling his network card? If I did understand correctly, then what do you expect to do about that? You wrote that you want to recreate/bind a UdpClient, but how would that go without an enabled network card?

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus Network card isn't the problem. I think the problem is that no packet is sent on a close connection request unlike TCP (SYN,ACK etc)? Best thing is probably to catch SocketException and use the ErrorCode provided

Comment: @LewsTherin "The user then disables the network interface on the system." That very much does sound to me like the network card is the problem.

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus Yes, but that was an example... it might as have been a closing the UDP client application or whatever. The problem is a "disconnect".. otherwise I don't understand the problem at all.

Comment: @LewsTherin There is no disconnect in UDP. And I do think that the OP is aware of that.

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus Exactly, that's why I think he has to wrap his code in a try catch block. Otherwise `Receive` won't return control back to the caller gracefully

Comment: @LewsTherin I'm not sure how the UDPClient behaves in that situation. It could very well be that the network card is disabled and `Receive` just keeps blocking without throwing an exception.

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus Shrugs.. no idea

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus Yes, I want to be able to handle the case of a disabled/unplugged network card. The intent of the code was to support a constant loop, attempting to prepare the socket for receiving data. If the network card does not exist, it would fail, the exception would be caught and it would try again in a set interval.

Also, when I initially made the code, I was under the assumption that disabling/unplugging the card would result in a `SocketException` when Receive was blocking. This was not the case. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UDP is completely stateless. The rule of thumb is: You cannot rely on anything. Not on sending, not on receiving, not on getting errors when something goes wrong.

UDP sits quietly and waits for the next packet. By binding it to an endpoint, you merely tell it to discard anything that is not sent explicitly to this endpoint. So if the user disables his network card, it still waits for packets that were sent to the bound endpoint, even though it just became impossible for packets to arrive. And as soon as you activate the card again, and someone sends to that endpoint, the UDP client will receive it, as if nothing happened.

Long story short: Your `UdpClient` is not the choice of software to find out if the network card was disabled. You will have to find out some other way and disable your `UdpClient` manually, if you really want to handle that case. For instance, you could initialize TCP on some other port. I am fairly certain that this would in fact produce an error if you then disable the network card.